# the contents of videoview to fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I have a videoview using for my splashscreen. The videoview occupies the top of the screen and down part its blank. I want the video to be played fullscreen.

here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.example.acer.myapplication.splash">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.test);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), first.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XML for the Video.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
```

**EDIT**

The Video has to be rotated to use in portrait mode. Use [this website](https://rotatemyvideo.net/) to rotate the video by 90 degrees and then set it as splashscreen.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the view you are currently seeing.

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: Won't that change the content of my video?

Comment: Yes it would, since the video you have added is in landscape mode, android plays it with the default size. You could stretch it but that would not be a good practice. I have added the expected video screen in the answer. Please check it.

Comment: is there any way in which I can get the content straight?

Comment: Think about it, your video is in landscape(width 1920 probably) and you if you set it as splashscreen, it will not cover fullscreen. You can stretch it, but it won't be good. To get the video content to work properly, you can create the video at 90 degrees using and then rotate it( I used after effects for this)

Comment: Or you could use your complete app in landscape mode.

Comment: Could you help me in getting the video stretched?

Comment: I would not suggest it, since that is a bad practice. Your current video screen will be forced to cover the full screen. To do it anyway, you can just specify the height of the VideoView to a custom value larger than the screen and use relativeLayout wrapper.

Comment: even with this it does not cover the fullscreen. some part at bottom is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152362/discussion-between-abhi-and-devk).